# How i can refresh this page (called add_user.php) when delete button already executed the sql too

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I wanna make delete with confirmation modal, the code below (js) for calling the div where delete modal contains Delete button (class is btn-ok).

HTML :

```
<a href="" data-href="add_user.php?iduser=<?php echo $iduser; ?>" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btn-rounded" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete">
<i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>

<div class="modal fade" id="delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <center>
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h2><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Konfirmasi Hapus Data</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">Anda yakin menghapus data ini?</div>
            </center>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <center>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Batalkan</button>
                    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-ok">HAPUS SEKARANG</a>
                </center>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript :

```
<script>
    $('#delete').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href', $(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));
    });
</script>
```

PHP :

```
<?php
require('koneksi.php');
$iduser = $_GET['iduser'];
$sqldel = "UPDATE bf_user_santara SET deleted='1' WHERE iduser='$iduser'";
if (mysqli_query($con, $sqldel)) {
    echo "Record deleted successfully";
    //$_SESSION['sukseshapus'] = 1;
} else {
    echo "Error deleting record: " . mysqli_error($con);
}
?>
```

But i dont know why, when the mysqli_query($con, $sqldel)) was executed, the page didnt show the message "Record deleted successfully", and i wanna the page reload to add_user.php, how to do that? I've already tried but didnt work for me. Thank you

Sorry for my bad english :)

P.s here i doing soft delete, so data on the database just changed deleted_id, and my query worked, just not working on that message & page reloading

Comment: `mysqli_query($con, $sqldel)` returns `true` if there is a connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reaload the page you can do like this in php.

```
header("Location: http://www.yourwebsite.com/add_user.php");
die();
```

And for display delete message you should store that message in session. Or you can do it using javascript but for that you need to do this with ajax and in success function you can display the message. So once confirmation model open, on click of OK button, you should redirect to add_user.php either using php or javascript like this:

```
window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";
```

Comment: Thank you, i've tried using reload option and it work perfectly, :)